# Set tag css property, before appending the tag to the DOM

Tags: jquery, html, css

I put into DOM div tag, using jquery `append()` method

I want that *before* putting, set div tag some css property, for example `visibility: "hidden"`

this doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

     $(".child").css({
         visibility: "hidden"   
      });

      $("body").append('<div class="child"></div>');


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SBAFk/

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: you are telling to keep name for unborn baby ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code cannot work since it does not create a new CSS rule but just searches for matching elements - and the new element cannot be found yet. The easiest way is to create the element, set its CSS properties and then add it to the DOM:

```
var div = $('<div class="child"></div>').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$('body').append(div);
```

Another option would be creating a new CSS rule matching the selector.

Comment: so are you saying that @bipen's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14979980/766570) won't work?

Comment: That will work too but the OP asked to do it before appending it to the DOM.

Comment: Well, this is top ranked in Google for "add .css to div before appending" and this is EXACTLY what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

problem in your code is, jquery is seraching for `child` class before it is apeended in the DOM.... which it will not be able to find since it is not inserted in the DOMtree..put your `.css()` code after appending the div

```
$(document).ready( function () { 
  $("body").append('<div class="child"></div>');

  $(".child").css({
     visibility: "hidden"   
  });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/SBAFk/3/)

Comment: i just voted you back up.. you shouldn't have got the downvote  (i was about to write the exact same answer as you).. your solution is sound.. it seems people tend to automatically up vote the guy with the most points.. sad